# An exact cover of an open set with in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with cubes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider an open set $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ being completely covered by a countable collection of boxes defined using the $d$-dimensional unit cube $Q = [0,1]^d$ as follows:
$$
Q_{n,k} = 2^{-n}Q + 2^{-n} k, \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}, k \in \mathbb{Z}^d
$$

Take the set, $I_0$ to be:
$$
I_0 = \{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d: Q_{0, k} \subseteq \mathcal{U} \}
$$

Then we define $I_1$ to be the set of all indices $k \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, such that $Q_{1, k} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$, but $Q_{1, k}$ are not contained in any of the boxes $Q_{0, k}$ and so on. In this fashion, we construct smaller and smaller boxes such that are all contained in $\mathcal{U}$. So we have the inclusion,
$$
\bigcup_{n \geq 0} \bigcup_{k \in I_n} Q_{n, k} \subseteq \mathcal{U}
$$
What I am stuck in is the reverse inclusion, that is each $x \in \mathcal{U}$ is inside at least one of
the constructed $Q_{n,k}$, that is,

$$
\bigcup_{n \geq 0} \bigcup_{k \in I_n} Q_{n, k} = \mathcal{U}
$$

is eluding me. I have tried to use boxes that are contained in some open ball surrounding the point $x$, but having difficulty in seeing why we are able to find such a box $Q_{n,k}$ with $k \in I_n$ for some $n$ satisfying $2^{-n} < \sqrt{\frac{2}{d}} \delta \leq \sqrt{2}\delta$, where $\delta$ is the radius of the open ball surrounding $x$.

**Edit:** This "decomposition" of $\mathcal{U}$ concerns a lemma in my text that says that any open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be covered exactly by at most countable collection of non-overlapping closed boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You practically got this.

For each $n$ and $k$ the diameter of $Q_{n,k}$ is equal to $2^{-n} \sqrt{d}$, which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now let $x \in \mathcal U$. All we have to do is to prove that there exists $n,k$ such that $x \in Q_{n,k} \subset \mathcal U$, for once that is proved then one simply chooses $n_1 \ge 0,k_1 \in \mathbb Z^d$ to satisfy two properties:

1. $x \in Q_{n_1,k_1} \subset \mathcal U$
2. $n_1 \ge 0$ is minimal with respect to the previous property.

It follows that $Q_{n_1,k_1}$ is in your collection, that is, $k _1\in I_{n_1}$.

To prove the existence of $n,k$, let $\delta > 0$ be any radius such that $B(x,\delta) \subset \mathcal U$. Since $2^{-n} \sqrt{d}$ converges to $0$, there exists $n$ such that $2^{-n} \sqrt{d} < \delta$. Now choose any $k$ such that $x \in Q_{n,k}$; this $k$ exists because for fixed $n$ the boxes $Q_{n,k}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z^d$ cover $\mathbb R^n$. It follows that $Q_{n,k} \subset B(x,\delta)$, because if $y \in Q_{n,k}$ then $d(x,y) \le 2^{-n} \sqrt{d} < \delta$.

Comment: @Mosher, thank you for the response. However, could you clarify how choosing $n$ large ($2^{-n} < \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{d}}$) and at the same time the smallest possible garuantees that $k \in I_n$.

Comment: That's not what the proof says. I rewrote it slightly, perhaps there was a clash of variables with too many uses of the variable $n$.

Comment: @Mosher, something seems still amiss. Suppose a $\delta$ is given so that $B(x, \delta) \subset \mathcal{U}$, but the least $n \geq 0$ for which $x \in Q_{n,k} \subset \mathcal{U}$ might not _fit_ inside $B(x, \delta)$. This could easily happen depending on the shape of $\mathcal{U}$, so that the for the least $n$ satisfiying $Q_{n,k} \subset \mathcal{U}$, $Q_{n,k}$ might partially intresect $B(x, \delta)$, while for the next $n$, the box $Q_{n,k}$ might be inside $B(x, \delta)$ while missing out $x$ completly.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether "the least $n \ge 0$ for which $x \in Q_{n,k} \subset \mathcal U$ does not fit inside $B(x,\delta)$". The fact that **some** $Q_{n,k}$ containing $x$ fits inside $B(x,\delta)$ guarantees for you that **some** $Q_{n,k}$ containing $x$ fits inside $\mathcal U$ (because $B(x,\delta) \subset \mathcal U$).

Comment: The open ball $B(x,\delta)$ is simply being used in this proof as an aid to show that **there exists** some $Q_{n,k}$ that contains $x$ and fits inside $\mathcal U$; then you pick one with the minimal value of $n$.